# Why can't I create a file in LocalApplicationData? C# , VS 2022, Windows 11

Tags: c#, file, permissions, visual-studio-2022

I know that there are restrictions to file operations, but `SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` is supposed to be for application use.

```
string _myFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyFile.txt"); //Line1
Console.WriteLine(_myFilePath); //Line2
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(_myFilePath)); //Line3
Console.WriteLine(File.Create(_myFilePath)); //Line4
```

This is the console output:

[image]

The program stops at the 4th line and VS 2022 shows this error:

[image]

How can I create or delete files/folders in `SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` ? Or which folder is recommended for this kind of file/folder operations?

Comment: Programs in the appdata directory can have different security settings and permissions, like Edgar mentioned, it is not the program which failed, its the file which doesn't have the right permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/696965/windows-11-folder-read-amp-write-permissions-don39.html

Comment: thank you AZ Software. In this case the problem was related to my antivirus software (data protection functionality). when I disabled the antivirus, I could create de file in this folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Windows 11, VS 2022 17.2.0 Preview 5.0 and NET 6.0 without administrator privileges:
Your code worked fine for me.

Output:

```
C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Local\MyFile.txt
False
System.IO.FileStream
```

But here is my suggestion:
Check the ACLs of your directory: Is your account permitted for creating new files?
(Right-click the directory -> Properties -> Security -> Select your own user and check your permissions.)

Usually you should not create files directly under your `%localappdata%` directory.
If you need a temp-file, I would recommend to use `Path.GetTempFileName()` for getting a unique file name.
If you want to store files for a longer time, then I would recommend to create a directory for your application in `%localappdata%` and save the files there.

Sample:

```cs
string myApplicationDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyApplication");
string myApplicationFile = Path.Combine(myApplicationDirectory, "myFile.txt");
if (!Directory.Exists(myApplicationDirectory)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Creating directory: {myApplicationDirectory}");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(myApplicationDirectory);
}
File.Create(myApplicationFile);
Console.WriteLine($"File created: {myApplicationFile}");
```

Output:

```
Creating directory: C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Local\MyApplication  
File created: C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Local\MyApplication\myFile.txt
```

Comment: Dear Edgar.Bro, the problem was related to a "Data Protection" feature of my antivirus software... When disabled this functionality, I could create the file in LocalApplicationData whithout problems...  Your comments about good practices regarding the creation of temporary or permanent files are correct and useful. I want to thank you for your help.